# Disabled input works wrong in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I have an input which sets to disabled when some condtition implements.
For example i have input with default value 20.

`<input type='number' id='main' value='20'>`

And i have added to oninput event folowing code:

```
var input=document.getElementById('main');
input.oninput=function(){
  if(input.value>20){
  input.disabled=true;
  }
}
```

Totally when you mousedown on increase button,the value will increment before you mouseup.

In Chrome the value stops at 21 as expected.

Try here:https://jsfiddle.net/u0obL5h2/3/

Answer (score 2):

Change your function to listen to `onChange` rather than `onInput`

Answer (score 0):

Pretty strange behaviour from firefox i guess.
The `input.disabled` is fired before the input resets the mouseup event.
So my solution which works in chrome and firefox is this:

```
var input=document.getElementById('main');
input.onmouseup = function() {
  if(input.value>20){
    input.disabled=true;
  }
}
```

Try it here:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MdqOjM

Answer (score 0):

Use "onchange" in place of "oninput".
Hope it will help.

```
var input=document.getElementById('main');
input.onchange=function(){
  if(input.value>20){
  input.disabled=true;
  }
}
```

Comment: That will not  works as expexted,onchange will execute after oninput,so your solution will even non set element to disable state,before u do not mouseup